# Impute Time Series using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a very large dataset, df, that is missing a large chunk of dates (all of August) and its respective data. The file looks like this

```
        Date              ID           Size          Total            Used     
        
        07/01/2020        A            200           5000             0.90     
        07/01/2020        A            150           5000             0.90
        07/02/2020        C            100           3000             0.60
        07/02/2020        E            600           2300             0.70
        09/01/2020        E            300           1000             0.90
        09/01/2020        E            200           7000             0.90
```

My desire is for the data to look something like this, and to ultimately fill in the missing dates and their respective values by using the median or something similar. The rows to be filled are roughly

```
           Date              ID           Size          Total            Used     
        
        07/01/2020        A            200           5000             0.90     
        07/01/2020        A            150           5000             0.90
        07/02/2020        C            100           3000             0.60
        07/02/2020        E            600           2300             0.70
        08/01/2020        D            600           2200             0.50
        08/01/2020        E            400           2000             0.40
        09/01/2020        E            300           1000             0.90
        09/01/2020        E            200           7000             0.90
```

This is my approach:

```
     import pandas as pd
     import numpy as np
     import datetime as dt


     idx = pd.period_range(min(df.date), max(df.date)
     df = df.assign(FillMean = df.size, df.Total, df.used)
```

However, I am still researching and not 100% sure of the syntax. Any suggestions is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest way to do this would be to:

1. Index the dataframe on your date column (`df.set_index`)
2. Sort the index
3. Set a regular frequency. For example, `df.asfreq('D')` would cover all of the 'missing days' and fill those rows with NaNs.
4. Decide on an impute policy. For example, `df.interpolate("time")` will impute the missing values using time-based linear interpolation.

Note, however, that you can only impute columns with a numerical dtype.